# Mapping multiple csv files in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Does anyone know if there is a way to pass a schema mapping to multiple csv without doing it manually? I have 30 csv passed through a data flow in a foreach activity, so I can't detect or set fields's type. (Because i could only for the first)
Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Can you just use ADF's "Infer data types" option and not worry about setting it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

A Copy Activity mapping can be parameterized and changed at runtime if explicit mapping is required. The parameter is just a json object that you'd pass in for each of the files you are processing. It looks something like this:

```
{
  "type": "TabularTranslator",
  "mappings": [
    {
      "source": {
        "name": "Id"
      },
      "sink": {
        "name": "CustomerID"
      }
    },
    {
      "source": {
        "name": "Name"
      },
      "sink": {
        "name": "LastName"
      }
    },
    {
      "source": {
        "name": "LastModifiedDate"
      },
      "sink": {
        "name": "ModifiedDate"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can read more about it here: [Schema and data type mapping in copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping)

So, you can either pre-generate these mapping and fetch them via a lookup in a previous step in the pipeline or if they need to be dynamic you an create them at runtime with code (e.g. have an Azure Function that looks up the current schema of the CSV and returns a properly formatted translator object).

Once you have the object as a parameter you can pass it to the copy activity. On the mapping properties of the copy activity you just Add Dynamic Content and select the appropriate parameter. It will look something like this:

[image: Mapping Properties]

Comment: The question was specific to data flows. With data flows, you do not need to specify a hardened schema. ADF can infer data types on each execution.